# Magento 2 emails sent but not delivered

Tags: magento2

We have migrated our website from shared server to VPS on godaddy. the website is running fine however we don't receive email notifications from Magento admin. We used to receive all notifications before we migrated such as customers sign up, order confirmation, invoices emails but now not us and not the customers receiving any emails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There some possibilities because of that your emails sending not work.

Check server CRON is running or not.

In case Sales emails check Asynchronous sending is enable or disable by **Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> General Settings -> Asynchronous sending -> Enable/Disable** . If its enable check by disable. If disable Asynchronous sending work means your server emails working but CRON not working. Because of that queued emails are not sending.

Comment: in admin everything is fine as i checked not only we are not receiving orders notifications also we don't receive emails notifications when customer use "Contact us" form or sign up on our website We used to receive all notifications by emails before migrating to VPS. We can try cron but what's the best way to set it up so that we will receive all emails right away?

Comment: Then check server email are working with php simple script.

Comment: what's the best way to check and test it?